# why angularjs has less plugins than jquery for web design, animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs. I have worked in jquery for which a lot of plugins are available, like royal slider,cube portfolio which really helps me in design particularly revolution slider and much more paid plugins. But in angular I couldn't find any plugins like that, I have to still rely on those plugins for improved designs and animations.

Is it okay to use those plugins as support and build my apps using custom directives or do I have to make it work using only angular pre-defined directives?

Kindly also advise me where I could improve my design in angular without relying on jquery and still able to produce design in more professional way. !!!

Comment: Don't limit yourself to pre-defined core directives. AngularJS is designed to work with jQuery as long as it is encapsulated in  custom directives. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)  and [AngularJS jqLite/jQuery API Refererence](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite).

Comment: Now i am doing it in thay way, but I had doubts whether it is a good practice or not, to incorporate jquery in one way or the other into an alternate framework.

Comment: Well you have two opinions. One from someone with a silver badge in AngularJS and one from someone who has only one upvote in the `angularjs-directive` category. I am voting to close this question as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Yes it is opinion based. I got your opinion thank you. I am familiar now with directives and being in jquery simplified angularjs for me. I don't know how to close this issue. It provided me with the required encouragement to proceed further. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The overall standard with AngularJS is to *not* use it in conjunction with jQuery. The reasoning behind this is that AngularJS handles DOM manipulations through its libraries, and you shouldn't be doing manual DOM manipulations (i.e. with a library like jQuery).

Now, all though this is the standard, you *can* still use jQuery libraries with AngularJS. You'd be surprised if you research more, how many AngularJS libraries there are that wrap jQuery components in AngularJS directives. In fact, one quick search led me to find [an AngularJS library for Revolution Slider](https://github.com/Karnith/angular-revolution).

If you're coming from a jQuery development background and are curious of the similarities/differences and how to do things the "Angular way", check out this link:

["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: very much appreciate your reply. I am researching the angular equivalent of various jquery plugins and it is good to use it in the angular way rather the jquery way. Thank you once again.

Comment: You are welcome! If you found this answer to be helpful, could you please pick it as the chosen answer/upvote it so others are aware. Thank you. :)